# Is possible to 2-way replace in PhpStorm or Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, phpstorm

I have some CSS code in my document include left and right words.

I need to replace `right` => `left` and `left` => `right`.

Is possible in PhpStorm or Notepad++  to replace these words simultaneous ?

Comment: I think it can be done using regex

Comment: Not in my knowledge. I think you can do it quick with multiple selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(right)|(left)`
- Replace with: `(?1left:right)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(right)     # group 1
|           # OR
(left)      # group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
    left    # replace with left
    :       # else
    right   # replace with right
)
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]